Owl carousel show double image in responsive settings items:1 in mobile
Owl carousel show double image in responsive settings items:1 in mobile
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme pt-16 xxl:pt-20 h-full" id="carousel8">
       <div class="group flex justify-around items-center centerwrap">
         <div class="centerwidth">
            <Img class="object-cover w-full" src="images/car/carslide1.png"></Img>
         </div>
         /* other content stuff */         
       </div>
       <div class="group flex justify-around items-center centerwrap">
         <div class="centerwidth">
            <Img class="object-cover w-full" src="images/car/carslide1.png"></Img>
         </div>
         /* other content stuff */         
       </div>
       <div class="group flex justify-around items-center centerwrap">
         <div class="centerwidth">
            <Img class="object-cover w-full" src="images/car/carslide1.png"></Img>
         </div>
         /* other content stuff */         
       </div>
    </div>


`owl-item.center .centerwrap given height 50rem , owl-item
.centerwidth image container width given 50% owl-item.center
.centerwidth given 100% width .. everythings fine but when , items:1
configuration gives in mobile view it show double image like provided
image example.. 



owl-carousel is deprecated also mentioned tiny-slider outdated, here is some of the alternative which i decide to try in,

swiper
slick
glide


Here items: 1 is set from 0 to 600px screen size, due to which only one image will be visible on the mobile.
With loop: true setting, when you reach the last slide, it will return to the beginning again.
Nav and Dots: This will allow you to see navigation arrows and dots, but you can remove these if not needed.
Make sure you haven't written any custom CSS that is affecting the layout of the Owl Carousel.
If the double image is still visible, try re-instantiating the Carousel or checking that there are no duplicate slides.
so please check below script
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#carousel8').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  dots: true,
  responsive: {
  0: {
    items: 1  // 1 item on mobile view
  },
  600: {
    items: 2  // 2 items for tablets
  },
  1000: {
    items: 3  // 3 items for desktop
  }
  }
});
});


i rechecked everything , i think there is nothing wrong with my code, and recently i saw owl-carousel actually deprecated long time ago, and they donot encourage to use it, so i decide to move from it
